# How to use user defined types in Settings

Tags: c#, application-settings, user-defined-types

I have a project which I want to be able to store a value in the Settings XML which represents a user defined type. I know about the browse button in the settings type drop down, but when I select that option and go to browse, the only available options are types from my references. No classes which are defined in my project are available, in fact my projects namespace doesnt appear in that list at all. I can select types I have defined in my core libraries (which are a reference), which have no difference in terms of their visibility / attributes to my projects type, and seemingly the only difference is that the type I want to use is in the project I want to add a setting to. Is it possible to add a setting which is of a type defined in the project whose settings you're modifying?

Heres a screenshot of the browse dialog for settings:

[image]

The projects root namespace is CartControllerForms, which isnt available in the list. I tried adding in the type by typing out the FQN in the Selected Type text field, but get this error:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the type you want to use marked as `[Serializable]`?

Comment: @DStanley No, but neither are the types in SmartCartCore which are available for selection. I suppose I could try quick, see if it makes a difference.

- Edit: Makes no difference :(